# gitlab ci job stuck, gitlab runner not picking up the jobs

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I got the right ci.yml, gitlab runner configured right.But still told me "This job is stuck because of one of the following problems. There are no active runners online, no runners for the protected branch, or no runners that match all of the job's tags: build Go to project CI settings"

my gitlab-ci.yml(very simple for test):

```
test:
  script:
    - echo 1231231
  tags:
    - build
```

and my gitlab runner configuration:
[gitlab runner configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtWPY.png)

I can confirm my runner is shared for projects and enabled untagged job.

I want to know how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your problem description, you might need to check that:

- the GitLab runner has the tag `build`. Jobs in GitLab CI/CD are picked by runners that have matching tags. If the tag `build` is not present in the runner configuration, the job will not be picked up.
  See "[How the runner uses tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#how-the-runner-uses-tags)"
- the runner is allowed to run on protected branches (in case your job is for a [protected branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html))
- the runner is active (not paused), as noted by the OP in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77713238/gitlab-ci-job-stuck-gitlab-runner-not-picking-up-the-jobs/77713383#comment137011174_77713383)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But My gitlab runner has `build` tag and also `ci.yml` has matching tags as your can see (very simple ci.yml uppon). And it isn't protected branch. Still not working, did I miss something?

Comment: ohh, I see.The runner is paused, just resume to accept jobs. Thanks again!

Comment: @coconut Good catch. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, open Project Settings -> CI\CD -> Runners and make sure "Enable shared runners for this project" tick is enabled.